# not sure how to pass link.codevalue in the rat method

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

- i am new to js.

  - i need to retrieve the values from the services.
  - I got all the values from the service.
  - but only id key i am not getting.
  - in link.code place I am getting url and the id appended to that url.
  - but not sure how to pass that value in the rat method.
  - i tried various ways like passing the values.
  - but thats not working.
  - can you guys tell me how to fix it.
  - providing relevant code below.
  - whole code in the gist.
  - i debugged also but still not able to find out.

https://gist.github.com/texirv0203/f4aefb951bbb4eb4d865dca568f91ce9

```or-tag-here
  rat()
  {
    var grid = $('#jumpingplayersGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    var finger = grid.finger(grid.select());
    grid.dataSource.remove(finger);
    $('#divdeletejumpingplayer').hide();

    let dancs = grid.dataSource;
    let currentData = dancs._data;
    let swimming;
    let todayDate = this.todayDate();

    console.log("finger---->" + finger);
    console.log("finger.ball---->" + finger.ball);
    console.log(" finger.swimming---->" +  finger.swimming);
    console.log(" values---->" );



    let data = [
        { 
          "id": "35369",
          "playerDtos" : [{
            "ball":finger.ball,
            "playerFox": finger.playerFox,
            "playerType": this.playerType,
            "playerData": this.encodeBase64,
            "notes": "",
            "ground": 123,
            "plane": 123,
            "url": "some-url",
            "categoryType": "",
            "Timestamp": todayDate,
            "userID": "876564",
            "addedByFox": $(".loggedUserFox").text(),
            "operationType": "delete",

            }]          
        } 
      ];

    this.SPORTService.getResponse("jumpings/player/", "post", data[0])
      .subscribe(data => {
        //console.log("DeleteData---->" + data);
          if (data.code == 'S001') {
          } else {
          }
        },
        err => {
        }
      );

  }


---> need toi use link.code


  this.SPORTService.getResponse(link.code, 'get', null)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.gridData = data.playerDtos;
            //that.dancs.data(jumpingMock);
            that.dancs.data(this.gridData);

          },
          err => {
          }
        );
```

**link.code comes from another method which is present in another file**

hey I created another gist there you can see the bear method present in whole file
https://gist.github.com/texirv0203/9719b28df9c49b27e2e357a8afd85aa6

```or-tag-here
bear(link, source): void {
        console.log("bear");
        //let columns;
        let title;
        let excelFileName;
        let basketballNo;
        let code;
        let netNo;

        let that = this;
        title = "tigerS";
        excelFileName = "ViewAiringsExport";
        this.selectedtigerId=link.id;

        //code = "basketballsaggregator/v1/basketball/airings/123/456";
        //code = "someLink/{id}";
        //tigerName
        //tigerType
        code = "someLink/" + link.id;

        let columns = [{
            field: 'noseRow',
            editable: false,
            template: '<span class="noseMenuRow" id="noseMenuRow"></span>',
            width: 25,


        ];
        let data = {
          "code": code,
          "columns": columns,
          "title": title,
          "excelFileName": excelFileName
        };
        this.van.openPopup(data,'basketball');
```

Comment: "need to use link.code" ... if only we knew what `link` was ...

Comment: @Roamer-1888  thanks for your reply link.code comes from method bear which is present in another file...can you tell me how to fix it :(

Comment: Maybe `rat(link.code)` ? Honestly, you really should try to provide a more concise sample of your problem.

Comment: @TGrif my codebase is very big that's the reason I pasted whole code in gist

Comment: Sorry, I'm nowhere near to being able to answer the question. I don't know nearly enough. In particular, it's not clear how `bear()` and `run()` relate to each other.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 hey I created another gist there you can see the bear method https://gist.github.com/texirv0203/9719b28df9c49b27e2e357a8afd85aa6

Comment: @ja ja This is not more concise at all...

Comment: @TGrif I tried to make it concise...but not sure how to do...can you help me out